# two controllers in one view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have two controllers, one for the users and one for the microposts.

What I'm trying to do, is to put on the **same view**, the users informations and the microposts form.

The issue is the url of this page is www.mywebsite.com/users/18 so I have only access to the users controller.

I tried to do:

render :file => '/posts/new' but it doesn't work.

The only solution I found is to put everything on one controller but it will be a mess.

I really want a separate controllers for each.

So I don't know how to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do, is to put on the same view, the users informations and the microposts form

I think you are trying to create a new `micropost` inside the `user` `show` view. If so, you can include the below:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: :microposts, action: :create) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When you submit the form, it will call the action `create` in the `microposts` controller.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working through Hartl's tutorial? Well, anyway, all you have to do is initialize all instance variables you need in the view in the controller action:

users/18 is probably pointing to users#show, thus you need to add something like

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build 
  ...
  end
...
end
```

in controllers/users_controller.rb (or something that fits your model) to initialize a new micropost for the micro post form, or just

```
@micropost = Micropost.new
```

if you don't have/need an association to the user. (Michael Hartl is doing it on the home page, though.)